# Prove that for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $\left| \ln \left(\frac{x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{y+\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}\right)\right| \leq \frac{|x-y|}{a}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, lagrange-multiplier

Let be $a > 0$. I have to prove that for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\left| \ln \left(\frac{x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{y+\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}\right)\right| \leq \frac{|x-y|}{a}$$

I think we use here Lagrange but I do not know how.

Any help?

Comment: Check that for $x=y$ you get $0\leq0$. For $x\neq y$ write the $|\ln(M/N)|\leq|x-y|/a$ as $\left|\frac{\ln(M)-\ln(N)}{x-y}\right|\leq 1/a$. Compute the derivative of $f(x)=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\right)$, which is $1/\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}$, which maximum is for $1/a$, for $x=0$.

Comment: MoonLightYzygy. Why not write a short answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let f(x)=ln(x+$\sqrt{a^2+x^2})\,\,\forall\,x\in R$
$$f'(y)=\lim_{x \to y}\vert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\vert$$
$$=\vert \frac{1+\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}}{y+\sqrt{a^2+y^2}} \vert$$
$$=\vert \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}\vert \le \vert \frac{1}{a} \vert$$
$$\therefore \vert f(x)-f(y) \vert \le \vert \frac{x-y}{a} \vert $$

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution,we need to prove that the derivative of this function is bounded above and we need Logarithmic identities of quotinent to construct such function
[image: the proof]